# What is the syntax for OrderBy in an entity using PHP 8 attributes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

According to Doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/tutorials/ordered-associations.html), one can order a field in an entity with `@OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})`. With PHP 8 attributes, a field definition may look like this:

```
    #[ORM\Column(length: 25)]
    private ?string $food_name;
```

However, adding a sort like this: `#[ORM\OrderBy({"food_name" = "ASC"})]` is not acceptable syntax. Nor is `#[ORM\OrderBy("food_name" = "ASC")]`.

Acceptable syntax such as `#[ORM\OrderBy('food_name = ASC')]` results in

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OrderBy::__construct(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type array, string given
```

For this use case, Food is a collection field in a ManyToMany relationship with Meal. I'm trying to accomplish a sorted field so that a template that uses `{% for food in meal.foods %}` will render a pre-sorted food name list.

A) Can this be accomplished in the Food entity? or
B) Should this be done in the Meal entity? or
C) Is a presorted field not possible?

If presorted is possible, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Does this work? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_orderby

Comment: You gave a string, try an array. `#[ORM\OrderBy(['food_name => ASC'])]`.

Comment: It's acceptable syntax, so I suppose I should accept it as an answer. I still need to figure out how to presort for the `food in meal.foods` case. In the Meal entity, that attribute results in `Argument #2 ($field) must be of type string, int given`. Any idea?

Comment: @[Marleen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3960296/marleen) The attribute that works is ` #[ORM\OrderBy(["food_name" => "ASC"])]`, which is what the cited documentation suggests. Please create your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute on Meal.foods:

```
#[ORM\OrderBy(["food_name" => "ASC"])]
private $foods;
```

See also the documentation here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_orderby